# How to configure typescript to work with webpack's resolve.modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, module, node-modules

Say, I have a webpack config like this:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  modules: ['my_modules', 'node_modules'],
},
```

So I have a special directory name `my_modules` that works similarly as the `node_modules` directories. All other examples and questions I found about getting typescript working with webpack's `resolve.modules` config is for absolute paths, none is for the directory name like my case.

So is there any way to make typescript understand the module resolution in webpack's `resolve.modules` configuration above? (having another directory name that works similarly as `node_modules`)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a combination of `baseUrl` & `paths` in `tsconfig.json` can help you, take a look at the (very informative)[documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

They provide an example that's very similar to your case:

> **Using "paths" also allows for more sophisticated mappings including multiple fall back locations**. Consider a project configuration where only some modules are available in one location, and the rest are in another. A build step would put them all together in one place. The project layout may look like:

```
projectRoot
├── folder1
│   ├── file1.ts (imports 'folder1/file2' and 'folder2/file3')
│   └── file2.ts
├── generated
│   ├── folder1
│   └── folder2
│       └── file3.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

The corresponding tsconfig.json would look like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "generated/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This tells the compiler for any module import that matches the pattern "*" (i.e. all values), to look in two locations: `baseUrl`, and `generated/`

```
import ‘folder2/file3’

    - pattern ‘*’ is matched and wildcard captures the whole module name
    - try first substitution in the list: ‘*’ -> folder2/file3
    - result of substitution is non-relative name - combine it with baseUrl -> projectRoot/folder2/file3.ts.
    - File does not exist, move to the second substitution
    - second substitution ‘generated/*’ -> generated/folder2/file3
    - result of substitution is non-relative name - combine it with baseUrl -> projectRoot/generated/folder2/file3.ts.
    - File exists. Done
```

---

In this case, instead of `generated/*`, you could use your `my_modules` instead:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "my_modules/*"
        "*",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```